# Why are git repos so much smaller than SVN repos?

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I have recently converted a huge SVN repository with 500k commits to several hundred git repos.

The git repos are tiny in comparison to SVN. My manager thinks I haven't done it properly! I used svn2git and I think it worked perfectly.

Just wondering what are the main reasons why it would be smaller?

Comment: Can you tell us how big the subversion repository was, and how big the git repository became?

Comment: I don't have access to the svn server right now, but just looking at one particular repo. It was 650MB in SVN and only 130MB in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[svnvsgit.com](https://svnvsgit.com/) answers your question:

> Subversion and Git repositories with equivalent data will have approximately the same size. Except for the case of storing a lot of binary files, when Subversion repositories could be significantly smaller than Git ones (because Subversion’s xdelta delta compression algorithm works both for binary and text files).

Under [Repository Site Benchmarks](https://svnvsgit.com/#repository-size-benchmarks) he compares SVN and Git and sees that:

> the difference of repository size is truly insignificant because the Git repository is only 10% smaller than the corresponding Subversion one

In conlussion:

- Git has an overall smaller repository size
- SVN will be smaller if you have a lot of binary files

If your Git repos compared size is **significantly smaller** (more than 20%) there is a real possibility that something went wrong.